# Web browser not loading full stylesheet after CSS changes on first refresh? Caching?

Tags: css, firefox, caching, google-chrome

In both chrome and Firefox, the browser doesn't load the full stylesheet after a change is made. I have to refresh the browser twice. The styles are all in one stylesheet, so this makes no sense to me.

The main culprit is that ul elements set to display:none are over-ridden by the user agent styles of ul,menu display block. However, if I refresh again, then my entire stylesheet loads. All my files and folders are stored on the work server. Is it a caching problem?

Comment: Are you using the HTML5 application cache?

Comment: Sounds like a caching problem, yes. Also check your server configuration.

Comment: Maybe some improper proxying (either local or of your internet- or hosting provider).

Answer (score 1):

To prevent caching of css files you can append a querystring. I do this when we update our main website.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://mysite.com/all.css?v=1.3">
```

I increment this whenever we do a release. If you are just testing your web server you can put in some dynamic code that generates the current time.

Comment: I've tried adding dynamic versions to the CSS file but the problem persists. It's very annoying because it makes live reload useless.

Comment: @KyleHyde - as this doesn't sound like a client-side issue you may want to edit your question and add your server configuration as well as any caching plugins/extensions you may be using.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, you can disable the cache when you're developing. Open the developer tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>), click on the Gear at the very bottom right, and check "Disable cache".

Comment: In Firefox it's a bit less comfortable, you need to set `network.http.use-cache = false` in `about:config`.